# Как менять местами значения внутри переменной?

Tags: python

Мне нужно, чтобы в новой переменной старые переменные менялись местами. То есть:

```
from random import randint

x=randint(0,9)
y=randint(0,9)

trial_1=
trial_2=
trial_3=
```

Нужно, чтобы в коде после знака = было 3 цифры (x, y и 0). И, чтобы эти три знака менялись местами в каждой переменной trial. Число 0 не должно стоять в начале переменной. Переменная должна на выходе быть одним числом, то есть, не (1,0,4)((например)), а 104.

Comment: ну например...

`trial_1=[x,y,0]
trial_2=[y,x,0]
trial_3=[x,0,y]`

Comment: Тогда в переменной trial_1 всегда будет один и тот же порядок, а мне нужно, чтобы при каждом запуске кода, менялся порядок в каждой переменной trial

Comment: "Число 0 не должно стоять в начале переменной. Переменная должна на выходе быть одним числом, то есть, не (1,0,4)((например)), а 104." - ну это уже фактически новая задача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужны все возможные перестановки трех значений, то нужно использовать функцию [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutations#itertools.permutations) из `itertools`:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import permutations

x = randint(0,9)
y = randint(0,9)

p = permutations([x, y, 0])
trials = list(p)
print(trials)
```

Пример вывода:

```
[(7, 8, 0), (7, 0, 8), (8, 7, 0), (8, 0, 7), (0, 7, 8), (0, 8, 7)]
```

> мне нужно, чтобы при каждом запуске кода, менялся порядок в каждой переменной trial

Если нужно, чтобы при каждом запуске кода выбиралось три случайные перестановки, то нужно с помощью функции [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) выбирать из списка `trials` три значения (случайно выбранных) и записывать их в переменные:

```
trial_1, trial_2, trial_3 = sample(trials, 3)
print(trial_1)
print(trial_2)
print(trial_3)
```

---

В принципе, можно было бы использовать `random.shuffle` (перемешивание), но тогда была бы вероятность, что в двух переменных окажется набор значений в одинаковом порядке.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте метод `rotate` класса `deque` из модуля collections:

```
from random import randint
from collections import deque

x = randint(0,9)
y = randint(0,9)

dq = deque((x ,y, 0))
print(dq) # deque([5, 6, 0])
dq.rotate()
trial_1 = list(dq)
dq.rotate()
trial_2 = list(dq)
dq.rotate()
trial_3 = list(dq)

print(trial_1) # [0, 5, 6]
print(trial_2) # [6, 0, 5]
print(trial_3) # [5, 6, 0]
```

Comment: `deque` - это метод? разве не класс?

Comment: класс, конечно. тмелось в виду "метод deque.rotate".